# QuickSort of Comparable[]

Tags: java, recursion, quick-sort

Here is the code for the QuickSort class that I created.

```
public class QuickSort {

        public static void sort(Comparable[] a) {
            quicksort(a, 0, a.length-1);
        }

        private static void quicksort(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi) {
            if(lo >= hi) return;
            int pi = partition(a, lo, hi);
            quicksort(a, lo, pi-1);
            quicksort(a, pi+1, hi);
        }

        private static int partition(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi) {
            int i = lo + 1;
            int j = hi;

            while(i <= j) {
                if(a[i].compareTo(a[lo]) <= 0) { 
                    i++; 
                }
                else if(a[j].compareTo(a[lo]) > 0) { 
                    j--;
                }
                else if(j < i) {
                    break;
                }
                else
                    exchange(a, i, j);
            }
            exchange(a, lo, j);
            return j;
        }

        private static void exchange(Object[] a, int i, int j) {
            Object tmp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = tmp;
        }
}
```

The code passed some simple tests (including duplicate values). I wonder is any bug in my code? Anywhere to improve?

Comment: Friendly reminder that `java.util.Arrays` has an optimized [`sort` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object[]%29)

Answer (score 10):

Javadoc on every method would be nice.

Change signature to `<T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] a)`.

```
public static void sort(Comparable[] a) {
```

Standard method to specify ranges is from inclusive to exclusive.

```
  quicksort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
}

private static void quicksort(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi) {
```

Why not "high" and "low"?

```
  if (lo >= hi) {
```

Your code never invokes quicksort with `lo > hi`. You'd better throw an `IllegalArgument` exception in this case.

```
    return;
  }
  int pi = partition(a, lo, hi);
  quicksort(a, lo, pi - 1);
  quicksort(a, pi + 1, hi);
}

private static int partition(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi) {
  int i = lo + 1;
  int j = hi;
```

You choose the first element as pivotal. Choosing as a pivot the element at a constant position allows construction of an antitest, an array on which your sort works in O(n^2). In your particular case, the antitest is pretty simple - an array in descending order, e.g. (5, 4, 3, 2, 1).

```
  while (i <= j) {
    if (a[i].compareTo(a[lo]) <= 0) {
      i++;
    } else if (a[j].compareTo(a[lo]) > 0) {
      j--;
    } else if (j < i) {
      break;
    } else {
      exchange(a, i, j);
    }
  }
  exchange(a, lo, j);
  return j;
}
```

It's better to name it swap.

```
private static void exchange(Object[] a, int i, int j) {
  Object tmp = a[i];
  a[i] = a[j];
  a[j] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Very nice answer by abra.
for future reference, the most important issue here is the O(n^2) time complexity - because of the pivot selection.

Answer (score 2):

Just three quick notes:

1. You could fix the compiler warnings with the following method declarations:

   ```
   public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] a)

   private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void quicksort(T[] a, int lo, int hi)

   private static <T extends Comparable<T>> int partition(T[] a, int lo, int hi)
   ```
2. I'd rename `a` to `input` or `data` for better readability.
3. `exchange` is usually called `swap`. I think more developers would find familiar the latter.